# React Native DatePicker NativeBase - How to disable specific dates

Tags: react-native, datepicker, native-base

Is it possible to disable specific dates using the DatePicker of NativeBase in React Native? I looked in the docs, and only found that is possible to specify a minimumDate and minimumDate, but I'm trying to disable some dates in this interval. Thanks!